# WCF / Android ksoap2 / a:DeserializationFailed error and I can't change maximum string content length quota (8192)

Tags: android, wcf, ksoap2

I am writting WCF WebService to work with my Android project. I have method called CreateOrder and everything works fine, untill I notice that if I am sending too large XML data file I have exception:

```
06-28 15:23:09.894: E/Błąd wątku mainThread / Sender(6988): java.io.IOException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 500
```

Then I have changed my Android project library from "ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies" to "ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-RC.4-jar-with-dependencies" and that's how error looks now:

> 06-28 15:18:47.124: E/Błąd wątku mainThread / Sender(6623): SoapFault
>   - faultcode: 'a:DeserializationFailed' faultstring: 'The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in
>   deserializing body of request message for operation 'CreateOrder'. The
>   maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while
>   reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the
>   MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
>   object used when creating the XML reader. Line 257, position 38.'
>   faultactor: 'null' detail: null

After I recognize what's going on I have changed sizes of quotas etc. I am working on this issue since 2 days can't find the solution. Maybe some of you see something wrong with my WCF / Config. I past also method from Android / LogCat, but I think it's WCF issue.

It's my WCF / App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
  </system.web>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="FoodsoftPortSoap11" 
                 closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
                 openTimeout="00:01:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 sendTimeout="00:01:00" 
                 allowCookies="false"
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                 <!--messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"-->
                 <!--useDefaultWebProxy="true"-->
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" 
                       proxyCredentialType="None"
                       realm="" />
            <!--<message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />-->
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="newHTTPBinding"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="basic" 
                binding="wsHttpBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="newHTTPBinding" 
                contract="FudeoRef.FoodsoftPort"
                name="newHTTPBinding">
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="" 
                binding="webHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="FoodsoftPortSoap11" 
                contract="FudeoRef.FoodsoftPort" 
                behaviorConfiguration="web"
                name="FoodsoftPortSoap11"  />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Android thread

```
Thread MainThread = new Thread() {
          @Override
            public void run() {
              try {               

                Log.v("K","1 "+order);
                final String METHOD_NAME = "CreateOrder";
                final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IService1/CreateOrder";
                final SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                Log.v("K","2 "+order);

                //request.addProperty("cXMLData", activity.getResources().getString(R.string.abc));
                //Log.v("XMLString", activity.getResources().getString(R.string.abc));
                //request.addProperty("cXMLData", TEST);
                Log.v("K","ROZMIAR "+TEST.length());
                request.addProperty("cXMLData", XMLString);
                Log.v("K","3 "+order);
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                Log.v("K","4 "+order);
                envelope.dotNet=true;
                Log.v("K","5 "+order);
                Log.e("envelope",String.valueOf(envelope));
                Log.e("envelope",String.valueOf(request));
                activity.runOnUiThread (new Runnable(){ 
                      public void run() {
                         Print.MessageInform(activity, String.valueOf(request));
                      }  
                        });
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                Log.e("K1",envelope.toString());
                Log.v("K","6 "+order);

                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                Log.v("K","7 "+order);

                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                Log.e("K",envelope.toString());
                Log.v("K","8 "+order);
                // Retrieve response object 
                ResponseString = envelope.getResponse().toString();
                Log.v("K","9 "+order);
                Log.e("Przebieg synchronizacji","2. Wysłano zamówienie: "+order);
               activity.runOnUiThread (new Runnable(){ 
                  public void run() {
                      //Print.MessageInform(activity, ResponseString);
                      Parser.ParseCreateOrder(order, ResponseString, activity);
                  }  
                    });
               }
             catch (final Exception exc) {
                 activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.e("Błąd wątku mainThread / Sender ", exc.toString());
                        }
                    });
            }
          }
       };
```

LogCat

> 06-28 15:24:26.744: E/Przebieg synchronizacji(6988): 1. Uruchamiam
>   proces wysyłania zamówienia: 3 06-28 15:24:27.104: V/K(6988): 1 3
>   06-28 15:24:27.104: V/K(6988): 2 3 06-28 15:24:27.104: V/K(6988):
>   ROZMIAR 8767 06-28 15:24:27.104: V/K(6988): 3 3 06-28 15:24:27.104:
>   V/K(6988): 4 3 06-28 15:24:27.104: V/K(6988): 5 3 06-28 15:24:27.104:
>   E/envelope(6988):
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope@42d6b658 06-28
>   15:24:27.104: E/envelope(6988): CreateOrder{cXMLData= 06-28
>   15:24:27.104: E/envelope(6988):  06-28 15:24:27.104:
>   E/envelope(6988):    0.0 06-28 15:24:27.104:
>   E/envelope(6988):     06-28 15:24:27.104:
>   E/envelope(6988):    1001 06-28 15:24:27.104:
>   E/envelope(6988):     06-28
>   15:24:27.104: E/envelope(6988):    0 ... 06-28
>   15:24:27.104: E/K1(6988):
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope@42d6b658 06-28
>   15:24:27.104: V/K(6988): 6 3 06-28 15:24:27.104: V/K(6988): 7 3 06-28
>   15:24:27.144: D/dalvikvm(6988): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6617K, 31% free
>   15375K/22168K, paused 30ms, total 32ms 06-28 15:24:27.164:
>   E/Dodaje(6988): order 3 06-28 15:24:27.164: E/Dodaje(6988): order 4
>   06-28 15:24:27.174: E/Dodaje(6988): order 5 06-28 15:24:27.174:
>   E/Dodaje(6988): order 7 06-28 15:24:28.224: I/Choreographer(6988):
>   Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its
>   main thread. 06-28 15:24:28.364: E/Błąd wątku mainThread /
>   Sender(6988): java.io.IOException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status:
>   500

Comment: This is solution or not I am just advising u good programming practice:
Why don't you tried **AsyncTask** to hit server??

Comment: first ensure tha a wcf client can consume this service. then compare the request of the working wcf client to the android one

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any service endpoints defined in your WCF service config (you do have client endpoints, which doesn't make any immediate sense).  Since you didn't define the endpoint(s) explicitly in your config file, WCF will provide default endpoints, with default bindings based on the address scheme.  In the case of `http://`, this will be `BasicHttpBinding` (unless you override the protocol settings in the config file).

Since you're getting default bindings, you're getting the default settings, and any changes you make to the bindings in your config file will not be applied to the service unless you a) make it the default binding configuration for that service or b) explicitly assign that configuration to a given endpoint.

To make a configuration the default for a given binding, simply omit the name attribute:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding closeTimeout="00:01:00"
             ......
```

However, this won't solve your problem as you're still using `BasicHttpBinding` (since there are no service endpoints defined).

The easiest solution for your situation is to change the client endpoints to service endpoints and assign your binding configurations (which you did, but they are currently client endpoints):

```
<services>
  <service name="<your service name>">
    <endpoint address="basic"
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="newHTTPBinding" 
              contract="FudeoRef.FoodsoftPort"
              name="newHTTPBinding" />
    <endpoint address="" 
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="FoodsoftPortSoap11" 
              contract="FudeoRef.FoodsoftPort" 
              behaviorConfiguration="web"
              name="FoodsoftPortSoap11" />
  </service>
</services>
```